# Deactivate crypt and enable automatic login

Tags: 13.04, encryption

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 with the home folder encryption. Now I want to disable the encryption and enable the automatic login.

But now is the question, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try following [this guide.](http://www.howtogeek.com/116179/how-to-disable-home-folder-encryption-after-installing-ubuntu/)  It should be just what you need.